# How to store images in mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Anybody has a quick example to insert an image in mongodb using mongoose and nodejs express

I read some examples but i cant understand how to do this?

I want to upload an image in a form

```
app.post('/videos/new', function(req, res) {
  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log('here i go');
    if(err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      ins = fs.createReadStream(files.file.path);
      console.log('insssssssssssss'+ins);
      ous = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/static/uploads/videos/' + files.file.filename);
      util.pump(ins, ous, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          next(err);
        } else { RegProvider.save({
           file: req.param(files.file.filename),
                   filename: req.param('filename')
                 }, function(error, docs) {
              res.redirect('/videos');
         });
        }
      });
      //console.log('\nUploaded %s to %s', files.file.filename, files.file.path);
      //res.send('Uploaded ' + files.file.filename + ' to ' + files.file.path);
    }
  });
});
```

Like this example but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: You are probably better off uploading the file to something like S3, and then just storing the public URL to that file in your database.  The massive size of image data can have some serious performance issues on almost any database.

Comment: The standard MongoDB way to handle this use case is to use GridFS: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS

Comment: this is not for massive storage... but tnx for the advise

Comment: JohnnyHK can you give me an example to upload a jpg file'''??

Comment: Similar questions have been asked several times on StackOverflow, so you could have a look at past answers.  If your images are unlikely to execeed the current 16Mb BSON document size limit, you can serialize the images as binary and save in a document rather than using GridFS.  Here's an example gist: [store/display an image in mongodb using mongoose/express](https://gist.github.com/2408370).

Comment: Can't you just use a type like Schema.Types.Buffer?

Comment: @AlexWayne I don't agree, one of the initial design goals of mongo was to store millions of images, CTO said so on the Changelog podcast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`util.pump` is [deprecated](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_pump_readablestream_writablestream_callback).

You might try out https://github.com/aheckmann/gridform or https://github.com/aheckmann/connect-multipart-gridform and see if they meet your needs.