# saving a picture to mongodb with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I want to save a picture in mongodb database and I'm using node.js.

There is no driver support for storing images for node.js.

How can I write a mini-driver for storing images in node.js?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate?   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046703/store-images-in-mongodb-using-mongoose-how-to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046703/store-images-in-mongodb-using-mongoose-how-to)

Comment: Yes. It solved my problem. Thanks for the link.  user645715

Answer (score 4):

There is in fact support for storing large files in all of the official MongoDB drivers, through the [GridFS API](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS).

Here's a link to the GridFS documentation for Node.js: http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle2.html.

Comment: Most images can be saved directly into a collection as a `Binary data`. Would be nice if you could a nice tutorial on how to do that with Mongoose.